# Identity with traces and a Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, kronecker-product

I'm studying on *Matrix Variate distributions* by Gupta and Nagar.
I can't figure out why the following identity holds:
\begin{equation}\text{tr}\{(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes \Psi^{-1})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})'\}=\text{tr}\{\Sigma^{-1}(X-M)\Psi^{-1}(X-M)'\}\tag{1}\end{equation}
which is equation $(2.2.3)$, page 56. The notation has the following meaning:

1. $X\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$, $M\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$;
2. $\text{tr}\{\cdot\}$ is the trace function;
3. $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$, $\Psi\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are symmetric and positively definite matrices;
4. $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product;
5. $\boldsymbol{x}\triangleq \text{vec}[X]$, $\boldsymbol{m}\triangleq \text{vec}[M]$, where $\text{vec}[X]\in\mathbb{R}^{pn}$ is the operator that stacks the columns $X_1$, $\dots$, $X_n$ of $X$ on top one each other, i.e.
   \begin{equation}X=\begin{bmatrix}X_1 & \dots & X_n\end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow \text{vec}[X]=\begin{bmatrix}X_1 \\ \vdots \\ X_n\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
   same for $\text{vec}[M]=[M_1' \cdots M_n']'\in\mathbb{R}^{pn}$.

The authors get the identity, without specifying how, by using the following theorem (1.2.22, page 9): if $A\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times m}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times q}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{q\times m}$, $D\in\mathbb{R}^{q\times n}$, $E\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, $X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ then
\begin{equation}\text{vec}[AXB]=(B'\otimes A)\text{vec}[X]\tag{2}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\text{tr}[CXB]=\text{vec}[C']'(I_q\otimes X)\text{vec}[B]\tag{3}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\text{tr}[DX'EXB]=\text{vec}[X]'(D'B'\otimes E)\text{vec}[X]=\text{vec}[X]'(BD\otimes E')\text{vec}[X]\tag{4}\end{equation}
where $'$ denotes the transpose operator and $I_q$ is the $q\times q$ identity matrix.

---

Here is my first attempt to get the identity $(1)$: it's easy to see that $\text{vec}[\cdot]$ is linear, thus
\begin{equation}\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m}=\text{vec}[X-M]\end{equation}
consequently from $(2)$,
\begin{equation}(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes \Psi^{-1})\text{vec}[X-M]=\text{vec}[\Psi^{-1}(X-M)(\Sigma^{-1})']\end{equation}
but $\Sigma$ is symmetric, thus $\Sigma^{-1}$ is symmetric, so
\begin{equation}(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes \Psi^{-1})\text{vec}[X-M]=\text{vec}[\Psi^{-1}(X-M)\Sigma^{-1}]\end{equation}
this means that the LHS of $(1)$ can be written as
\begin{equation}\text{tr}\{(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes \Psi^{-1})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})'\}=\text{tr}\{\text{vec}[\Psi^{-1}(X-M)\Sigma^{-1}]\text{vec}[X-M]'\}\end{equation}
now for the [general property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#cite_note-5) of the trace $\text{tr}[AB]=\text{tr}[BA]$ holds
\begin{equation}\text{tr}\{(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes \Psi^{-1})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})'\}=\text{tr}\{\text{vec}[X-M]'\text{vec}[\Psi^{-1}(X-M)\Sigma^{-1}]\}\end{equation}
and, for the the [general property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_inner_products) of the vectorization $\text{vec}[A]'\text{vec}[B]=\text{tr}[A'B]$,
\begin{equation}\text{tr}\{(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes \Psi^{-1})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})'\}=\text{tr}\{\text{tr}\{(X-M)'\Psi^{-1}(X-M)\Sigma^{-1}\}\}\end{equation}
now, trivially, the trace of a scalar is the scalar itself, so
\begin{equation}\text{tr}\{(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes \Psi^{-1})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})'\}=\text{tr}\{(X-M)'\Psi^{-1}(X-M)\Sigma^{-1}\}\end{equation}
and finally, once again for the property $\text{tr}[AB]=\text{tr}[BA]$, I conclude
\begin{equation}\text{tr}\{(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes \Psi^{-1})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})'\}=\text{tr}\{\Sigma^{-1}(X-M)'\Psi^{-1}(X-M)\}\end{equation}
which is not $(1)$ because $(X-M)'$ is not in the right place.

---

Here is a second slimmer attempt. From $(4)$, by considering $D=I_n$ follows the identity
\begin{equation}\text{tr}[X' E X B]=\text{vec}[X]'(B'\otimes E)\text{vec}[X]\end{equation}
thus, by exploiting this formula,
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}\text{tr}\{(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes \Psi^{-1})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{m})'\}&=\text{tr}\{(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes \Psi^{-1})\text{vec}[X-M]\text{vec}[X-M]'\}\\
&=\text{tr}\{\text{vec}[X-M]'(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes \Psi^{-1})\text{vec}[X-M]\}\\
&=\text{tr}\{\text{tr}\{(X-M)'\Psi^{-1}(X-M)(\Sigma^{-1})'\}\}\\
&=\text{tr}\{(X-M)'\Psi^{-1}(X-M)\Sigma^{-1}\}\\
&=\text{tr}\{\Sigma^{-1}(X-M)'\Psi^{-1}(X-M)\}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
which is the same result of the previous attempt.

---

It sound strange to me the hypothesis that $(1)$ contains a typo because in another book, *Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory* by Muirhead, it is expressed implicitly the identity $(1)$ (in equation $(1)$ of page 79).
I don't think that Gupta and Nagar have merely copied an erroneous result from Muirhead.

Comment: Note that there are two different vectorization conventions. If you "stack rows" instead of stacking columns, you end up with the rule
$$
\operatorname{vec}(AXB) = (A \otimes B') \operatorname{vec}(X).
$$
This seems to explain the discrepancy. I suspect that Gupta and Nagar use this alternative convention.

Comment: Note that the two vectorization conventions are related in the following way: if $\operatorname{vec}_1$ stacks columns and $\operatorname{vec}_2$ stacks rows, then we have 
$$
\operatorname{vec}_2(X) = \operatorname{vec}_1(X').
$$
This should allow you to check everything I've said for yourself.

Comment: You're right. Both Gupta&Nagar and Muirhead define $\text{vec}[\cdot]$ by stacking columns, but also define (quite strangely) $\boldsymbol{x}\triangleq\text{vec}[X']$,  $\boldsymbol{m}\triangleq\text{vec}[M']$ (and this was my missing point), thus it turns out the identity $(1)$. Thank you so much for your insight, it was helpful.

Comment: Why do you write MathJax code the way you do? I pointed out some things in response to one of your other question, and you seem to have disregarded that. Notice that Ben Grossmann's comment above has proper spacing and your question doesn't, and I explained why that happens in my comment under your other question.

Comment: No Michael, I've not disregarded your suggestion. Rather, I'm grateful to you because I've learned something new thanks to you. The reason why I've used a bad MathJax code is because I've copied & pasted a TeX code from my personal notes, which I've written previously with my wrong method. I will be more careful in future.